# Java Stack Linked list

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have declared a Queue of objects Node with the following lines of code:

```
Queue<Node> queue;
queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

However, when I declare a stack of the Node objects, by replacing the Queue with stack, it doesn't work. Why is it so? Also, what exactly does

```
queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

mean? Does it mean that a linked list of Node objects is being created and can be in the Queue?

I am taking open courseware to learn about Data Structures and Algorithms and I am a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because java.util.LinkedList implements java.util.Queue but it is not a java.util.Stack though it has push and pop methods. Stack is a legacy class and its usage is not recommended, but if you still want to use it, this is the way to go

```
Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, for legacy reasons, `Stack` is a class, not an interface.  So a `LinkedList` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `Stack`.

The `Deque` interface declares LIFO operations (although it also declares FIFO operations), and `LinkedList` implements `Deque`.

When you do

```
queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

you're creating a `LinkedList` but are referencing it via the type `Queue`, such that only the FIFO operations are exposed.  This would ensure that later, other implementations of `Queue` could by swapped in by changing only the line above.

Answer (score 2):

`Queue<Node> queue` says that variable queue is of type "Queue of Nodes".  `Queue` is an interface not a class.

Java's LinkedList class implements the Queue interface, so `queue = new LinkedList<Node>();` is perfectly ok.

The Java Stack is an actual class that doesn't implement the Queue interface, so you can't just substitute it in.

Comment: Thanks. Then is it OK to declare like this-  Stack<Integer[]> intStack = new Stack<Integer[]>(); ? As in, the Stack class implements an array of integers?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that a linked list of Node objects is being created and
>   can be in the Queue?

No it means that the underlying datastructure uses for the Queue is a LinkedList, and that you can add object of type `Node`

You should read up on  generics if your are not familiar with this construct `LinkedList<Node>()`